# Looping test scores in file input/output

Tags: python, loops, file-io

For my Programming assignment I had to

> Create 2 programs using File input and output. The first program
>   prompting the user to input 5 test scores, then write that to its own
>   line in a file named tests.txt. The second program then reads
>   tests.txt, displays all of the scores, and the average of the scores.

So I turned in the following code and got an okay-ish grade on it, with the following feedback:

> I deducted points for poor design. When you find your code repeating
>   almost similar lines, use a loop. You need a loop in both programs.

So, I'm stuck in the fact of cleaning up the design and putting a loop in them (although I thought that is what my `For Loop` was doing). Help and clarification would be very much appreciated =D

Here is the first program:

```
def main():
    score1=int(input("Please input your first score: "))
    score2=int(input("Please input your second score: "))
    score3=int(input("Please input your third score: "))
    score4=int(input("Please input your fourth score: "))
    score5=int(input("Please input your fifth score: "))

    score_file=open("tests.txt","w")

    for count in range(1, 5):
        score_file.write(str(score1) + "\n")
        score_file.write(str(score2) + "\n")
        score_file.write(str(score3) + "\n")
        score_file.write(str(score4) + "\n")
        score_file.write(str(score5) + "\n")

    score_file.close()

main()
```

Here is the second program:

```
def main():

    display_score=open("tests.txt", "r")
    for count in range(1,5):  
        score1=int(display_score.readline())
        score2=int(display_score.readline())
        score3=int(display_score.readline())
        score4=int(display_score.readline())
        score5=int(display_score.readline())

    display_score.close()

    average=(score1+score2+score3+score4+score5)/5

    print("Here are your scores you inputted: ", \
      score1, ", ",score2,", ",score3,", ",score4,", ",score5,\
      sep="")
    print("Your average is: ", average, "%",\
      sep="")

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading scores:

```
all_scores = []

for x in range(5):
   all_score.append( int(input("score: ")) )

print all_scores
```

the same way you can write to file

```
for one_score in all_scores:
    score_file.write( str(one_score) + "\n")
```

but you can do it in one loop:

```
for x in range(5):
    score = input("score: ")
    score_file.write( score + "\n")
```

BTW: in first program you don't need to convert score to `int()` and then to `str()`

You can use `for` to add scores (or use special function `sum(all_scores)` for it)

```
sum_score = 0

for one_score in all_scores:
    sum_score = sum_score + one_score

print( sum_score / len(all_scores) )
```

`len(all_scores)` give you number of scores on the list

of course you can use `for` loop to read numbers from file

```
all_scores = []

for count in range(5):  
    all_scores.append( int(display_score.readline()) )

print( all_scores )
```

There is special function to print elements from list

```
print( ", ".join(all_scores) )
```

All values will be connected by `", "`

Comment: Thank you very much for the comprehensive answer! I'm still in my first programming class and I very much enjoy it, but it does get a bit disheartening when I can't figure this stuff out. Hopefully I can keep overcoming the obstacles though, and of course can always come here to great people like yourself who are willing to help out awful newbies like myself! Have an excellent day!!

Comment: I always believe you should start with C

Comment: I started with `C` 20 years ago :)

Answer (score 1):

Comments:

- both your programs are actually wrong - your `for` loop reads 5 values, 5 times (for a total of 25 score entries)
- whenever you find yourself with numbered variables (`score1`, `score2`, etc) it is usually a good sign you should be using a list
- `with` is a better way to deal with files; it always ensures they get closed properly
- `str.format()` (new-style string formatting) is usually faster and easier to read than string concatenation

Here is a simplified version of the first program

```
def main():
    with open("tests.txt", "w") as score_file:
        for tag in ["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth"]:
            prompt = "Please input your {} score: ".format(tag)
            score  = int(input(prompt))
            output = "{}\n".format(score)
            score_file.write(output)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

which runs like

```
Please input your first score: 1
Please input your second score: 2
Please input your third score: 3
Please input your fourth score: 4
Please input your fifth score: 5
```

and of the second:

```
def average(lst):
    return float(sum(lst)) / len(lst)    

def main():
    with open("tests.txt") as score_file:
        scores = [int(line) for line in score_file]

    print("Here are your scores you inputted:")
    print(", ".join(str(score) for score in scores))

    print("Your average is: {}".format(average(scores)))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

which runs like

```
Here are your scores you inputted:
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
Your average is: 3.0
```